# Updating an array column row in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm just wondering if anyone could help with something I'm attempting with postgres. Currently what I want to do is add onto an array of a specific row, for example in node.js I can `.push` new values into an array. Is there something like this I can do in postgres?
Something I can do is select that row, inject a new value and re-set the value onto it but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: There are lots of [array functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) so you can say things like `update t set c = c || 6` to push `6` onto the end of the array in column `c`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Well it depends what you mean in terms of sample data, how would you want it formatted? Like a normal programming array or like a PG array?